# How to copy branch policies while creating a new branch(git) in TFS

Tags: git, tfs, git-branch

We will create new branches(Git) for every release in `TFS 2018`. The problem is we have several ***branch policies for our branches***, every time whenever we create a new branch we have to manually create new branch policies. We do really want to get rid of this everytime.

Is there any way while creating a git branch which also copies the branch policies from the source branch itself?

Currently, I don't see any configuration like this in TFS (below image)

[image]

Comment: What Git branching model have you adopted? Branch policies should generally only be used for long-term, stable branches that you don't intend to delete.

Comment: @DanielMann We will create a separate branch for every release i.e dev_1.2, dev_1.3 etc., developers will create a feature branch/bugfix branch from this parent branch(dev_1.2),once dev_1.2 is completed and shipped we will lock this branch and create another new branch called dev_1.3 where we again need to create branch policies and permissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't such a feature to copy branch policies while creating a new branch in TFS.

You have to set the policies for each branch manually for now.

There's already user voices submitted to suggest the feature, you can go and vote them up to achieve it in future release...:

- [Have branch police template to store the branch policies usually set
  for most branches](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32334574-have-branch-police-template-to-store-the-branch-po)
- [Share single branch policy by multiple branches](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/14911392-share-single-branch-policy-by-multiple-branches)